# Help with cycle function in Ethereum Blockchain

Tags: nft, function

I am trying to understand the use of a particular function:

```
cycle(uint256 vaultId, uint256[] _desiredIds, uint256 maxIterations, bool acceptAny)
```

What is the purpose of this function? Why is called? I try to find documentation about it but there is not anything available or I just don't know where to look.

An example of a transaction that this function used is here:
[example](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4c70fe2b6761941a6cd43715997203d323ebd0338d8f19e7db704d247d24cd1a)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have the function implementation? The contract isn't verified and no source code is provided.

Comment: Yeah I know....this was the issue I had....I couldn't undertand how this works....so I hoped this is a generic function

Comment: I found a some code here https://gist.github.com/0xfoobar/07c0d49287f3186051fc09f48045e5f8. I've no idea what it does, yet.